# Which factor determines the numbers of Numa nodes?

Tags: cpu, vmware, esxi, numa

**SITUATION**

I am running a Virtual Machine(CentOS7) based on ESXi 6.5.

- BIOS(NUMA topology): enabled
- OS(NUMA topology): enabled
- Virtual Machine OS: CentOS7
- - Host OS: ESXi 6.5
- - vCPU: 56
- - Sockets: 56

No matter how I change the number of vCPUs or the number of sockets, there is always **ONE NUMA NODE** on the VM. By reading the blog [NUMA And vNUMA – Back To The Basic](https://www.teimouri.net/numa-vnuma-back-basic/#.WtTA6tOuxo4), I find that the numbers of NUMA node are no difference between assigning cores or sockets.

I also find some **advanced settings** on [the documentation of ESXi 6.5](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/6.5/vsphere-esxi-vcenter-server-651-resource-management-guide.pdf), but I do **NOT** know to use the following arguments appropriately.

- cpuid.coresPerSocket
- numa.vcpu.maxPerVirtualNode
- numa.autosize.once
- numa.vcpu.min
- numa.vcpu.followcorespersocket

**WANT**

What I want is that there are two NUMA nodes, or I can control the numbers of NUMA nodes.

**QUESTION**

1. Which factor determines the numbers of Numa nodes?
2. How to modify the numbers of Numa nodes(Detailed steps, please)?

Comment: Regarding the second question, can you be more specific? What are you trying to do? Did you try to look it up on the Internet? Are you facing a particular issue? Why do you care about the number of NUMA nodes?

Comment: @HadiBrais My Virtual Machine have 56 CPU cores, but only one NUMA node. This status (like a SMP system not a NUMA system) causes low performance. So I want to change the number of NUMA nodes from one  node to two nodes.

Comment: What kind of VM are you using? What's the host OS? What's the guest OS? How come the VM has 56 cores and one NUMA node but in the question you're showing only 16 cores and two NUMA nodes?

Comment: @HadiBrais Well, CentOS7 based on  ESXi 6.5, which are all bespoke softwares. What I showed is just a example not real status. Can you answer both questions in principle?

Answer (score 3):

> Which factor determines the numbers of Numa nodes?

From the perspective of the hardware, the physical layout of processors (cores) and main memory modules is what determines the number of NUMA nodes in a system. A NUMA node consists of a collection of cores, some other logic and memory units, and a collection of memory modules that can be accessed by these cores with a much smaller latency compared to the other memory modules.

But from the perspective of the OS, if the OS is not NUMA-aware, by default in most (all?) systems, the BIOS will configure the system so that the physical address space is interleaved across the physical NUMA nodes. So from that perspective, the whole system would like a single NUMA node, even though there are multiple NUMA nodes physically. Even for a NUMA-aware OS, it's usually possible to enable node interleaving from BIOS or the OS. Doing that makes the whole system to be treated as a single NUMA node. In addition if the OS is running on a VM, the VM itself must be configured to enable NUMA.

> How to modify the numbers of Numa nodes(Detailed steps, please)?

You'll have to ensure that ESXi 6.5 is configured to expose a *virtual NUMA topology* to guest operating systems. So you most probably have a configuration issue. See [this](https://www.teimouri.net/numa-vnuma-back-basic/) and [this](http://frankdenneman.nl/2016/12/12/decoupling-cores-per-socket-virtual-numa-topology-vsphere-6-5/).

Comment: For the first question, can the answer be that ---- the numbers of **Memory Controller**? I read the picture from a [blog](http://frankdenneman.nl/2017/10/05/vm-memory-config-exceeds-memory-capacity-physical-numa-node/)

Comment: @CHENJIAN No, not necessarily. For example, the [IBM POWER7](http://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs252/sp17/papers/POWER7-Server-IBM2011.pdf) has two memory controllers, yet it's an SMP system.

Comment: @CHENJIAN Yes you can. Did you see the links in my answer? I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: Thank you. I saw your links. But I can not understand it clearly. Maybe I lack of those knowledge, and I must read them many times.